# Is it possible to use Time Intelligence DAX functions with MS Access data sources?

Tags: powerbi, ms-access-2016

I'm using trying to use the DATESYTD() DAX function in Power BI in a model which uses an **MS Access database as data source** and I can't just make it work.

Is it possible that connections from Power BI to MS-Access databases are using **Direct Query mode** and that **time intelligence** functions are **not supported in this case**?

Comment: Direct query isn't supported in Access you'll be importing the data. You most likely have gaps in your dates, if you not using a calender table. Please post and example of the data and the DATESYTD code you are using

Comment: I'm already using a Calendar table in the Power BI model. I exported the Access tables & queries I'm using to Excel spreadsheets and used these as data sourced of Power BI instead of Access and now the DATESYTD() function is working without changing anything else. So I think that Power BI only uses Direct Query for accessing MS Access.